# hashbytes returns different values for int?

Tags: sql-server, sybase

Running the following on SQL Server got `0xE864ECE8888043B67277C8B2CEFE96AD315FCCA4`.

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(max)));
```

On Sybase the following SQLs return `0xEB408DDC4FA484E6BEFDF5954E56A2198C7A9FAB`

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(8000))), hashbytes('SHA1', 10 )
```

Why the SHA1 got different values on different databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible issue with MSSQL and Sybase running on cpu's with different endianness.

Consider the following run against Sybase ASE running on linux (I get the same results for Sybase ASE on Solaris/x86, too):

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(8000))                  ),hashbytes('sha1',10                  )
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(8000)),using         lsb),hashbytes('sha1',10,using         lsb)
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(8000)),using         msb),hashbytes('sha1',10,using         msb)
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(8000)),using unicode_lsb),hashbytes('sha1',10,using unicode_lsb)
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(10 as varbinary(8000)),using unicode_msb),hashbytes('sha1',10,using unicode_msb)
go

 ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab

 ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab

 ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab 0xe864ece8888043b67277c8b2cefe96ad315fcca4

 ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab

 ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
 0xeb408ddc4fa484e6befdf5954e56a2198c7a9fab 0xe864ece8888043b67277c8b2cefe96ad315fcca4
```

As you can see, I get both of the values you've mentioned; with the %CCA4 match coming from running **hashbytes** **using msb** or **using unicode_msb**.

What is your Sybase version?

```
select @@version
```

Comment: The Sybase version is `Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 22779 SMP SP122 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp12x/3662/64-bit/FBO/Sat Apr 19 05:48:19 2014`

Comment: hmmmm, so both should be running the same endianness; does MSSQL's hashbytes have support for a 'using {msb|lsb}' clause and if so, what values do you get for the 2? 'course, regardless of using clause I can't get the cast/varbinary to generate the %CCA4 string ... hmmmm ...

Comment: ... likely explained by Bogdan's comment about varchar(8000) != varchar(max); would be curious to see what MSSQL generates for varchar(8000)

Comment: It got the same hash value after I added `using msb`.